# Using RecyclerView in Fragment that added in MainActivity, showing double items, items behind items

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity, gridview, android-recyclerview, grid-layout

When scrolling down, it shows up grid items but behind items there are same items showing. Don't know why this happening. Using Custom adapter, Grid layout Manager. Here, I'm adding fragment in activity and Recyclerview layout is inflating in fragment and custom row is inflating in recyclerview.

[showing items behind items when scrolling, click this to view the screenshot of my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyRjW.jpg)

MainActivity onCreate method ::

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.containerGrid, new FragmentGrid()).commit();
        }
}
```

FragmentGrid class ::::

```
public class FragmentGrid extends Fragment {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
VivzAdapter vivzAdapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_grid, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycleView);

    int spanCount = 3; // 3 columns
    int spacing = 50; // 50px
    boolean includeEdge = false;

    vivzAdapter = new VivzAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(vivzAdapter);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(spanCount, spacing, includeEdge));

    return rootView;
}


public static List<Information> getData() {
    List<Information> data = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] images = {R.drawable.gridee, R.drawable.gridee, R.drawable.gridee, R.drawable.gridee, R.drawable.gridee, R.drawable.gridee, R.drawable.gride, R.drawable.gride, R.drawable.gride, R.drawable.gride};
    String[] names = {"Garlic Nan", "Caffe Latte", "Ice Cream with Ceramal", "Noodle Foodie", "Rice Organ", "Jesan", "Hemal", "FoodMe", "Noodle", "Rice Organ"};
    String[] prices = {"209", "103", "760", "120", "450", "23", "90", "87", "67", "109"};

    for (int i = 0; i < images.length && i < names.length && i < prices.length; i++) {
        Information current = new Information();
        current.title = names[i];
        current.price = prices[i];
        current.iconId = images[i];
        data.add(current);
    }


       return data;
    }

}
```

VivzAdapter ::

public class VivzAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;

List<Information> data = Collections.emptyList();

public VivzAdapter(Context context, List<Information> data){
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = data;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Information current = data.get(position);
    holder.foodPrice.setText(current.price);
    holder.productNameG.setText(current.title);
    Picasso.with(context).load(current.iconId).noFade().resize(150,150).centerCrop().into(holder.foodImage);
    //Picasso.with(context).load(current.iconId).resize(240, 120).into(holder.foodImage);


    holder.foodImage.setImageResource(current.iconId);

}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView foodImage;
    TextView productNameG;
    TextView foodPrice;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        foodImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodImage);
        productNameG = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.productNameG);
        foodPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodPrice);
    }
}
```

}

activity_main Layout ::

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/containerGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:name="com.pos.hassanmashraful.recyclerviewdick.FragmentGrid"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

custom_row ::: Layout Implementation

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/foodImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#55000000">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productNameG"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/productNameG"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="17sp"

            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/foodPrice"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/productPrice"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:textStyle="italic|bold" />


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

:::::  RecyclerView :::: Layout Implementation

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.pos.hassanmashraful.recyclerviewdick.FragmentGrid">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, Fragment is creating everytime, so it shows items behind items.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.containerGrid, new FragmentGrid()).commit();
        }
}
```

Change the code to this

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.containerGrid) == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.containerGrid, new FragmentGrid()).commit();
    }
}
```